# Python: comma-delimited list from a list of sets

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[
  {u'self': u'https://jr.com/Option/134', u'id': u'134', u'value': u'AI'},
  {u'self': u'https://jr.com/Option/135', u'id': u'135', u'value': u'E'}
]
```

Is there a way to come up with a comma-delimited "values" as: `AI, E`
I think I can do something like:

```
l = []
for x in l:
    val = x['value']
    l.append(val)
print l
final_l = ','.join(l)
```

but was wondering if I can do it in less code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save a few lines thanks to [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
values = ','.join(item['value'] for item in lst)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [
...   {u'self': u'https://jr.com/Option/134', u'id': u'134', u'value': u'AI'},
...   {u'self': u'https://jr.com/Option/135', u'id': u'135', u'value': u'E'}
... ]
>>> values = ','.join(item['value'] for item in lst)
>>> values
u'AI,E'
```

Comment: what if item doesn't have 'value' key? It'll give you KeyError.

Comment: @minitoto: silencing exceptions with no reason is never a good idea. The exception that you suppress now may cause unexpected behavior later. In that case you're not preventing any error, you're just delaying it, making it harder to debug, or maybe introducing serious security bugs.

Comment: it means a code snippet you gave with a potential error, i recommend to do it like this ','.join(item['value'] for item in lst if item.get('value'))

Comment: Andrea is right. This principle has a name and is known as "fail fast": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast . It may seem a contradiction, but fail-fast systems are the most robust.

Comment: @minitoto: the error is there, whether you suppress it or not. I would be *very* surprised to have a list of 5 items and a string with just 3 values. I prefer an exception to stop the process, rather than let the error propagate (possibly causing more problems)

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: foo = [
   ...: {u'self': u'https://jr.com/Option/134', u'id': u'134', u'value': u'AI'},   {u'self': u'https://jr.com/Option/135', u'id': u'135', u'value': u'E'}
   ...: ]

In [2]: ", ".join([x.get('value') for x in foo])
Out[2]: u'AI, E'
```

Comment: @minitoto Cheers. "Assume nothing about your inputs" :o)

Comment: `.get()` defaults to `None`. You should provide a string as a default value if you really want to suppress exceptions. (Even though [errors should never pass silently](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), which is an important principle)

Comment: Fair comment @AndreaCorbellini :o) `.get('value, '')` would be better for situations that don't fail loudly, yeah

Answer (score 0):

```
','.join(['1','2','3','4'])
```

is one way to create a comma-delimited sequence based on an input list/tuple of strings. In this case the result is `'1,2,3,4'`

In your case, your command might look like this (assuming you want to join 'values' of each dictionary element:

```
','.join([x['value'] for x in l])
```

Answer (score 0):

This comprehension does it easily:

```
>>> s = [
... {u'self': u'https://jr.com/Option/134', u'id': u'134', u'value': u'AI'},   {u'self': u'https://jr.com/Option/135', u'id': u'135', u'value': u'E'}
... ]
>>> ', '.join(x['value'] for x in s)
u'AI, E'
```